# My first sample cron job not working

Tags: linux, centos

I am new to Linux, when I try to execute a cronjob like below,

```
crontab -l
```

no cronjob for root

crontab -e its moving to /tmp/crontab.xxx

but not moving to /etc/crontab, so I have manually try to move /etc/crontab and tried to run some sample cronjob like below to run and show echo output in terminal  for every one minute like bellow and mkdir for test, and restarted crond service

```
/1 * * * * echo meeting at 12pm
/10 * * * * cp /root/test /root/test1
```

but it has not shown anything like installing crontab and not got any output also, can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
*/1 * * * * echo meeting at 12pm
*/10 * * * * cp /root/test /root/test1
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ,but still nothing worked tried the same code ,but directory test1 and echo output also not showing in terminal ...